# totalling a value from firebase in vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to total a price from firebase where the `addtoCart` value is true.

I then would like to display this value in my html file.

I am using vue.js to do this and I keep hitting a wall. can anyone help with this

HTML

```
<li v-show="book.addToCart" v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" >
        <div class="details">
           <!--displays the current book title-->
          <h3 @click="handleDelete(book)">{{ book.title }}</h3>
           <!--displays the current book author-->
          <p>By {{ book.author }}</p>
          <!-- displays the image -->
          <img :src="book.image">
          <p >{{ book.price }}</p>
        </div>
        <div :class="{icon: true, fav: book.addToCart}" @click="handleUpdate(book)">
          <span class="material-icons">favorite</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 @load="handleTotal(book.price)">Total:{{ Total }}</h3>
```

script

```
const handleTotal=(book) =>{
      const docRef = doc(db, 'books', book.id)

      totalDoc(docRef, {
      for(i = 0, i < books.length, i++){
        if(books.addToCart){
        const Total = Total + book.price
        console.log(Total)
        return Total
      }
      }
    })
```

Thanks

I have tried using a v-for in order to total the value there and also computed values.

I expected to see a total value output to the HTML file.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I cannot get the price of each book to create a total to display at the bottom of the page.

Comment: But you didn't provide any firebase code details. Your question is a little bit unclear. Can you explain it in a detail?